# No entra al metodo POST | php

Tags: php

lo que pasa es que cuando intento enviar mi formulario, pero no entra al método post ¿me podrían ayudar por favor?
Lo unico que quiero es que entre al POST para despues modificar una base de dato, en la imagen esta el codigo php que estoy utilizando

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    ?>
            <input type="text" name="ciudad" value="<?php echo $mostrar['CIUDAD']?>" >
            <input type="submit" value="modificar" name="modificar">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>

<?php
require 'includes/app.php';
$db = conectarDB();
 session_start();
 $nom=$_SESSION['NOMBRE'];
 $id=$_SESSION['ID_USUARIO'];
 $apellidoP= '';
 if ($nom==null && $id==null){
     header('Location: /index.php');

}
$query = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE ID_USUARIO = '{$id}'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($db, $query);
var_dump($_POST);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    header('Location: /menuDeUsuario.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: en el `<form action="">` no tienes agregado el archivo `.php` donde se ejecuta tu codigo del servidor.

Comment: @EdgarGc, si action está vacio, el post se hace a la URL actual, ese no es el problema.

Comment: @Stuart Somera, que te muestra el var_dump($_POST) que tienes cerca del final? Un array vacio?

Comment: O falta código en tu pregunta o necesitas organizar mejor. Veo que intentas llenar el formulario leyendo este resultado de la BD: `while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))`, pero no veo que obtengas antes ese resultado. Debes hacer la consulta primero y luego crear el formulario leyendo los datos de la consulta.

Comment: En mi caso preferiría no dejar `action` vacío. En algunos casos usuarios dicen que existen comportamientos extraños. Incluso, según esta respuesta en HTML5 > "no está soportado, por lo que es una mala práctica". -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396161/12429790